# Moving specific extension up one directory level

Tags: windows, batch-file

My current folder structure goes as follows:

```
E:\Videos\Movies\Random Folder Name\Subs\Random File Name.srt
```

I would like to move my `.srt` files up one level so it reads:

```
E:\Videos\Movies\Random Folder Name\Random File Name.srt
```

I would prefer this to be a `.bat` file, but am willing to use PowerShell.

~EDIT~

I found something online that partially works and edited it to my needs:

```
@echo off
set thisdir=%cd%
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /ad') do (
    cd /d "%%~dpnA"
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ('dir /b /ad') do (
        echo Level 2 Directory: %%~dpnB
        cd /d "%%~dpnB"
        for /f "delims=" %%C in ('dir /b /ad') do (
            echo Level 3 Directory: %%~dpnC
            cd /d "%%~dpnC"
            move *.srt ..\
            cd..
            rd "%%~dpnC"
         )
    )
)
```

This works, but only for the first folder, I can't seem to make Level 2 recursive as that is the level with random movie names.  I tried replace for /f with for /r, but it was a no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answers already given work, I still wanted to try and figure out how to perfect the code to my exact needs.  Couldn't accomplish this with CMD, so I looked into powershell (which was easier for me to grasp for some reason) and coded this:

```
$sourcefolder = "F:\Videos\Movies\*\Subs\"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $sourcefolder | where {$_.PSIScontainer -eq $false}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $destinationFolder = Split-Path -Parent $file.Directory.FullName
    move-item $file.FullName $destinationFolder
}
```

It doesn't specify .srt files, but they are the only extension located in that folder.  Thank you for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner:

```
forfiles /m *.srt /s /c "cmd /c move @file .."
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but I have other srt files on another level and this moves them up when they are actually fine to be where they are at.  Thank you though!

Comment: Looking back at this, I could've used it and dealt with the 100 files that get improperly moved by hand.  Thank you again for this!

Answer (score 1):

Full code (you can run this from any drive now):

```
@echo off
cd /d E:\Videos\Movies\
for /r %%i in (*.srt) do move "%%~dpnxi" "%%~dpi.."
pause
```

This looks for all files with type `.srt` and `move`s them to the folder it was found in -1 directory (`%%~dpi` is the directory it was found in, adding `..` to a path removes the last directory, so `C:\Users\..` would put you at `C:\`).
**PS**: This time I have tested this, and it works.

Comment: I'll give this a test when I get home, but the directory "Random Folder Name" literally is random.  That level contains folders named after movies.  I just mention that, because of looking at that code, obviously it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah, okay. This will be an easy fix.

Comment: 1. I have other videos located on my E:\ drive that have subtitles, so I need it to SPECIFICALLY follow the path that I gave in OP, where as this script appears to grab ANY/ALL .srt files in ALL folders located on E:.
2. Your code doesn't just move the .srt files one level up, it pulls them to wherever the bat file is run, no matter how deep the folder structure.

Comment: Ok, using your current edit moves the files one level too high, but appears to be working recursively and correct otherwise!

Comment: I'll look into it, the next edit should work perfectly.

Comment: Ok, so I didn't mention in my OP that I have srt files already located in the "Random Movie Name" level (although I did specify the subs folder :P ), so this script makes those move up a level when they should remain where they are at.  I only have about 100 of these, so I can work with this no problem, BUT I figured I would ask to see if it's possible to point this at say:

    cd /d E:\Videos\Movies\*\Subs\

If not, that's fine. Thank you for the help so far, it works flawlessly! Again, I can work with this small amount of files since your script is gonna be handling about 4100 movies!!!

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to block out said *.srt files located in the folders with *.srt files properly placed.

Comment: Ok, no worries!  Like I said, this already works great and I can use it!